# How put a logo in android marcket for a application android

Tags: android, google-play

hello
on android market of htc the application we can a logo

How put this logo for our application ?

Answer (score 0):

i think in the Manifest of your Application you can change the Icon of your Application like this :

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon_marmara" >
```

Comment: NO, i do not change the icon but the logo of my application in android market

Answer (score 0):

NO, do not change the icon but the logo of my application in android market

Answer (score 0):

Okay then, what about

```
<application android:logo="@drawable/sweet_logo">
```

?

Answer (score 0):

```
    The ActionBar will use the android:logo attribute of your manifest,
    if one is provided. That lets you use separate drawable resources
    for the icon (Launcher) and the logo (ActionBar, among other things).


    setDisplayUseLogoEnabled() Enables the use of an alternative image
    (a "logo") in the Action Bar, instead of the default application icon.
    A logo is often a wider, more detailed image that represents the
    application. When this is enabled, the system uses the logo image defined
    for the application (or the individual activity) in the manifest file,
    with the android:logo attribute. The logo will be resized as necessary
    to fit the height of the Action Bar. (Best practice is to design the logo
    at the same size as your application icon.)

    To replace the icon with a logo, specify your application logo in the
    manifest file with the android:logo attribute, then call
    setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true) in your activity.
```

Thanks to [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735649/android-icon-vs-log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735649/android-icon-vs-logo)o