# Android icon vs logo

Tags: android, icons, manifest, graphical-logo

The `<application>` tag for the Android Manifest contains a [logo attribute](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#logo) which I have never seen before. What is the difference between your application's icon and its logo? Is it used purely for market?

Comment: Very true! However it doesn't show up in intellisense in Eclipse! Seems like platform wants to add a new feature for developers to make their logo(Start up screen) and reference it directly from manifest.

Comment: It shows up in intellisense in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

> The ActionBar will use the android:logo attribute of your manifest, if
>   one is provided. That lets you use separate drawable resources for the
>   icon (Launcher) and the logo (ActionBar, among other things).

Source: [Android: How to change the ActionBar "Home" Icon to be something other than the app icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351479/android-how-to-change-the-actionbar-home-icon-to-be-something-other-than-the-a/6351736#6351736)

---

> setDisplayUseLogoEnabled()
>       Enables the use of an alternative image (a "logo") in the Action
>   Bar, instead of the default application icon. A logo is often a wider,
>   more detailed image that represents the application. When this is
>   enabled, the system uses the logo image defined for the application
>   (or the individual activity) in the manifest file, with the
>   android:logo attribute. The logo will be resized as necessary to fit
>   the height of the Action Bar. (Best practice is to design the logo at
>   the same size as your application icon.)

Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Style

---

> To replace the icon with a logo, specify your application logo in the
>   manifest file with the android:logo attribute, then call
>   setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true) in your activity.

Source: http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-3.0.html#api

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the full answer! This makes much more sense.

Comment: If the best practice is to set both as the same size, why would you use the logo? or maybe they meant just the height?

Answer (score 13):

It appears that:

- `android:logo` is available in API Level 10, but not API Level 8
- using `android:logo` without `android:icon` does not set the application icon in the app drawer

My hunch is that "logo" refers to a company logo instead of an application icon.

Comment: This is probably the case, although I can't really tell. Until someone else answers definitively, I'll have to assume this is the case. Thanks!

Comment: `R.attr.logo` is available since API Level 11, so `android:logo` too. The `ActionBar` is also available since API Level 11. You don't need to set a logo before API Level 11, because Android used the old theme from API Level 1 to API Level 10. A new theme (Holo) was used since API Level 11. That is why everything I mentioned was available since API Level 11.