# How to use a different icon for action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-icons

I made an icon for my Android app but I want to use a different file for the action bar. So on icon for app section, and one icon for action bar. How can I do that ?

Comment: This question has already been answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705414/changing-the-action-bar-icon

Comment: @Philio Yes but in that post he asked for changing it by Java. Im not. I want to change it on android, for example by xml. If that's possible tho.

Answer (score 0):

From official documentation:

> By default, the system uses your application icon in the action bar,
>   as specified by the icon attribute in the  or 
>   element. However, if you also specify the logo attribute, then the
>   action bar uses the logo image instead of the icon.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Logo