# changing home icon with ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am attempting to change my home icon to a drawable.  I am using the following code:

```
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.some_image);
```

This is not working!  I have the image set in my theme, so perhaps this can not be overridden...

I have tried on gingerbread and honeycomb so far...

Comment: What happens when you temporarily remove it from your theme?

Comment: It still does not work when removing from theme.  I did get it to work by changing a few things...Trying to nail down what the problem was and then will post an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was I had the declared a logo in the android manifest with the following line:

```
<application
   ....
   android:logo="@drawable/some_icon">
</application>
```

The icon declared in my theme was overriden by getSupportActionBar().setIcon().

For more info on icon vs logo see this SO:
[Android icon vs logo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735649/android-icon-vs-logo)