# Remove padding from android:logo

Tags: java, android, xml, android-actionbar, padding

When I use `android:logo` and display the view's boundaries I see that it has some additional padding on the left. How can I remove this? I was also to remove margin from `android:icon` since it can be fetched using `android.R.id.home`.

Is there such an identifier or other programatically way to fetch the logo view element?

Comment: possible duplicate of [remove padding around action bar left icon on Android 4.0+](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026007/remove-padding-around-action-bar-left-icon-on-android-4-0)

Comment: @Tanis.7x This is surely not the icon. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735649/android-icon-vs-logo

Comment: check out the accepted answer. It details how the spacing is applied to the ImageView with ID `android.R.id.home` and how to remove that spacing.

Comment: @Tanis.7x Ehm.. I know about `android.R.id.home`, but this is not related to the logo. `android.R.id.home` is related the **icon** which is different to the **logo**

Comment: Both the logo and the icon use the same ImageView. If that ImageView has no margin or padding but you are still seeing some, then there is probably something wrong with your Drawable. See https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/widget/ActionBarView.java