# What is ActivityInfo's banner for?

Tags: android, icons, android-manifest, graphical-logo, android-banner

### Background

I know there are already logo and icon (difference is explained [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735649/android-icon-vs-logo)).

### The problem

Starting with API 20 ("L"? or maybe Android wear?) , there is now a new one, called "[**banner**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageItemInfo.html#banner)". Here's what the documentation says about it:

> A drawable resource identifier (in the package's resources) of this
>   component's banner. From the "banner" attribute or, if not set, 0.

So this doesn't give much clues about what it is...

The problem is that I don't know what it is, and can't find any info about it.

### What I've tried

I've tried finding about this on the Internet, but because "banner" is such a generic name, I didn't find anything interesting...

Of course, I've also tried searching about this on the documentation of activity ([**here**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) and [**here**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)), but didn't find anything...

### The question

1. Where is it used for?
2. Is it for Android "L" or Android wear ? or maybe both?
3. Why has Google decide to make it?
4. Where can I read about it?
5. Are there any guidelines about it?
6. Depends on the answers, do you think it will somehow be part of the support library?

Answer (score 7):

It's for Android TV.

From the [l developer preview reference docs](https://developer.android.com/preview/reference.html):

> A Drawable resource providing an extended graphical banner for its
>   associated item. Use with the application tag (to supply a default
>   banner for all application activities), or with the activity, tag to
>   supply a banner for a specific activity.
>
> The given banner will be used to display to the user a graphical
>   representation of an activity in the Leanback application launcher.
>   Since banners are displayed only in the Leanback launcher, they should
>   only be used with activities (and applications) that support Leanback
>   mode. These are activities that handle Intents of category
>   Intent.CATEGORY_LEANBACK_LAUNCHER.
>
> This must be a reference to a Drawable resource containing the image
>   definition.
>
> Must be a reference to another resource, in the form
>   "@[+][package:]type:name" or to a theme attribute in the form
>   "?[package:][type:]name".
>
> This corresponds to the global attribute resource symbol banner.

You can also read a bit more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/preview/tv/design/patterns.html).

Essentially a banner is just a launcher icon for the leanback launcher. For example, if your app is compatible with both phones/tablets, and android tv, specifying a banner will let you have an alternate (rectangular) icon for the leanback launcher on android tv.

In this image, I specified the banner to be a red shape drawable. By default this will be your apps launcher icon.

[image: Banner Example]

I don't think it will be part of any support library, as it's specific to Android L on the TV. But to use it, you will need to be targeting L.

Comment: How did you find it? it's not on the "application" documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html , http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html . It's also not available as a content assist item. Searching for the exact (partial) text you've written doesn't show its origin. Also, can you please try to answer the questions I've written?